# Configure node.js chat

Tags: node.js, mongodb, session, express, socket.io

I am trying to install and run this node.js chat: https://github.com/dual3nigma/Mejorando.la-Chat. 
When I type "npm install" and "node server" it starts, but with an Express error. I think the reason is in the config.json file.

This is my config.json file. I've only changed the db name and port of the config.sample.json file and added my twitter / facebook keys:

```
{
    "port": 721,
    "host": "localhost",
    "db": {
        "name": "V1chatCCI"
    },
    "twitter": {
        "consumerKey": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
        "consumerSecret": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
    },
    "facebook": {
        "appId": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
        "appSecret": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
    },
    "session": {
        "secret": "",
        "key": ""
    }, 
    "cookie": {
        "secret": ""
    },
    "secure": false,
    "loginsecure": false,
    "key": "",
    "cert": "",
    "sentry": "dsn"
}
```

What do I need to put in the session secret/key section? The error on localhost:721 is:
`Express
500 Error: secret option required for sessions`

Comment: Ask the library's author. And tell him that he might want to put that info into the readme (which currently is empty).

Comment: He never is conected on Twitter or another social network...

Comment: Mail him? https://github.com/dual3nigma includes his mail address.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to put anything in those sections, as they're used used internally by express handling sessions. Any values (even just random strings) should fix your problem.

Comment: I put anything in those sections and now don't load. What I need put in "cookie"

Comment: Yes... And BTW, how I can configure Mongodb? Because the code have a "db" variable